# Kie server 7.5.0 default user

Tags: wildfly, kie-server, drools-kie-server

I have deployed a Kie Server 7.5.0 over a Wildfly 10, I can enter the login page of the Kie workbench, but I haven't been able to find out which is the default admin user or how to add my own one. I see Wildfly has an add_user script and an access management in its console, but I don't know if this is the way to enable access to Kie and how to proceed.

Do I have to specify a boot parameter in Wildfly with -D or something? How can I enable a user to access Kie Server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Kie-server.war uses applicationRelam for authentication and authorization. You can create ApplicationRelam user using /bin/add-user.sh script. You can use below command:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh -a User1 admin@123 -g admin,kie-server
```

Comment: Thanks! This has worked. I suspected that Kie was relaying on something like that (like when you use a datasource) but I couldn't find how I had to add the user. I had executed _add-user_ adding a role, but not with a group as you have pointed, and the command-line was slightly different.